# Rotating a Square with a circle inside, having dots on top of the circle

Tags: rotation, processing, processing.js

Okay guys Here is the scenario, in this picture there is a box and inside of that box there is a circle. Now as you can see there is four points on top of the circle and four corners of the box. These dots are actually ellipse. By means of the dots we can reshape the images. Now i what i want to do is to add rotation around its center i.e. rotation for both circle and the box. The problem being for the rotation is that the dots are on top of the circle and while rotating their position needs to be maintained and also the other corners point. Any inputs how this can be done?

[image: Conceptual Diagram]

Comment: You could use a CSS3 [transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) with a rotate [transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

Comment: can u point me out in some direction. i am not sure how to do it.

Comment: [This should help.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Comment: By means of processing code can it be done?

Comment: OOH! Whoops. I didn't realize `processing` was actually the name of a programming language. Now it makes more sense- I don't know that language; sorry. Upvoting so someone else who does know can help, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`rotate()`](http://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) to apply a transformation to the coordinates matrix.

like:

```java
void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
}
void draw() {
  background(255);

  //using frame count to rotate
  float a = radians(frameCount%360);

  // move coordinates so you can draw at origin
  // rotates always use origin as axis
  translate(width/2, height/2);

  //clockWise
  rotate(a);
  //counterClockWise
 // rotate(-a);
  noFill();
  rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  ellipse(0, 0, 100, 100);

  ellipse(-50, 0, 4, 4);
  ellipse(0, -50, 4, 4);
  ellipse(-50, -50, 4, 4);
  ellipse(0, 50, 4, 4);
  ellipse(50, 0, 4, 4);
  ellipse(-50, 50, 4, 4);
  ellipse(50, 50, 4, 4);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(50, -50, 4, 4);
}
```

There is this amazing tutorial on 2D transformations:

http://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/

Comment: but the rotation in the above code neither clock-wise or anti-clockwise. it is properly following the mouse

Comment: Now it does ;) (code edited above). That was just an example on how to use rotate, it was not clear that you need it to keep spinning... Check it out